# Magento 2 docker install: What is my admin user and password.

Tags: magento2, admin, magento-2.0

I have a Magento 2 installation using Docker as can be found here: https://github.com/ajmyers01/magento_docker

I have the site spinning up and can see the storefront, and when I go to access the admin url and log in using the credentials I specified in my docker-compose file it doesn't work and doesn't give an error message.

I'm unsure how to login, any insight as to, if my docker-compose isn't set up correctly to set the admin user, if there is a default admin user. Feel free to pull the repo and attempt it yourself. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looking on your files the user and password are **magento2**, but you can use this command to show all users:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:list
```

To show:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+--------+
| id | username        | email                         | status |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+--------+
| 1  | admin           | admin@example.com             | active |
| 2  | nextadmin       | nextadmin@example.com         | active |
+----+-----------------+-------------------------------+--------+
```

To change the password you can use:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:change-password
```

And to create a new:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --admin-email=admin@magento.tld --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you check the file: https://github.com/ajmyers01/magento_docker/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

You can see:

```
    environment:
        ...
        - M2SETUP_ADMIN_USER=magento2
        - M2SETUP_ADMIN_PASSWORD=magento2
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, I know what I configured, and I tried that but it doesn't let me log in and doesn't throw and error. I think it may be getting overwritten some where else.

Comment: Check your database admin_user: `select * from admin_user` and check that you have an admin user called magento2

Comment: You can also [create another admin user](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-admin.html).

Comment: I've confirmed that the user exists, and is active.

Comment: Clear cache recompile-di

Comment: @osrecio can you elaborate ?

Comment: Check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html

Comment: https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-command-line-tool-binmagento.html